# Python unittest import issues

Tags: python, flask, importerror, unit-testing

This is my project set up:

```
my_project
    ./my_project
         ./__init__.py
         ./foo
              ./__init__.py
              ./bar.py
         ./tests
             ./__init__.py
             ./test_bar.py
```

Inside `test_bar.py` I have the following import statement: 
`from foo import bar`

However when I run `python /my_project/tests/test_bar.py` I get this error:

`ImportError: No module named foo`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try `import sys; sys.path.append('..')` in `test_bar.py`. A better solution would be to modify `sys.path` based on the absolute path of my_project.

Comment: I would like to ideally organize the code such that i don't have to do that....What would be a better way to organize the code?

Comment: There's no need to mess around with `sys.path`; that's the wrong way to go. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685483

Comment: My structure mimics the example you linked...if you look at the comments below: "Thanks, for the example but I'm sure that if you will run test_app.py it will complain that is not able to find 'app'. Think that test must pass before the package is deployed to Python include path." That is exactly the issue I am having.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about what is on your `PYTHONPATH`.  The toplevel package for your project is `my_project`, so that must be the start of any import for  something in your project.

```
from my_project.foo import bar
```

You could also use a relative import, although this isn't as clear, and would break if you ever changed the relative location of the module you were performing this import from.

```
from ..foo import bar
```

---

Ideally, the `test` folder is not a package at all, and is not part of your application package.  See pytests's page on [good practices](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules).  This requires that you add a `setup.py` to your package and install it to your virtualenv in develop mode.

```
pip install -e .
```

---

Don't run the tests by pointing directly at a file within your application.  After structuring/installing your project correctly, use the discovery mechanism for whatever framework you're using to run the tests for you.  For example, with pytest, just point at the test folder:

```
pytest tests
```

Or for the built-in unittest module:

```
python -m unittest discover -s tests
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/my_project/')
```

Now you can import

```
from foo import bar
```

Comment: I use the embedded version of Python, and found this to be the simplest solution, to make the import work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative imports:

```
from ..foo import bar
```

https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

but i think too that using absolute paths by [installing](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) your project in venv is better way.

Comment: I would like to ideally organize the code such that i don't have to do that....What would be a better way to organize the code?

Comment: @AtulBhatia you can move dependent code to outer level or maybe make foo or whole project as separate app with setup.py